# How do you correctly use boost::make_shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, boost, boost-asio

This simple example fails to compile in VS2K8:

```
    io_service io2;
    shared_ptr<asio::deadline_timer> dt(make_shared<asio::deadline_timer>(io2, posix_time::seconds(20)));
```

As does this one:

```
shared_ptr<asio::deadline_timer> dt = make_shared<asio::deadline_timer>(io2);
```

The error is:

> error C2664: 'boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer::basic_deadline_timer(boost::asio::io_service &,const boost::posix_time::ptime &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const boost::asio::io_service' to 'boost::asio::io_service &'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `asio::deadline_timer` has a constructor that requires a non-const reference to a service. However, when you use `make_shared` its parameter is `const`. That is, this part of `make_shared` is the problem:

```
template< class T, class A1 > // service is passed by const-reference
boost::shared_ptr< T > make_shared( A1 const & a1 )
{
    // ...

    ::new( pv ) T( a1 ); // but the constructor requires a non-const reference

    // ...
}
```

What you can do is wrap the service up into a `reference_wrapper`, using `ref`:

```
#include <boost/ref.hpp>

asio::io_service io1;
shared_ptr<asio::deadline_timer> dt = // pass a "reference"
    make_shared<asio::deadline_timer>(boost::ref(io1));
```

This takes your instance, and puts it into an object that can be converted implicitly to a reference to your isntance. You've then essentially passed an object *representing* a non-const reference to your instance.

This works because the `reference_wrapper` really stores a pointer to your instance. It can therefore return that pointer dereferenced while still being `const`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Had no idea about boost::ref. Was it created in part to get around this type of thing, or are there other uses?

Comment: @Apple: It was designed pretty much for this reason. For example, `boost::thread` will make a copy of its arguments for the new thread, but if you want to actually pass a reference `boost::ref` works there too. It's used whenever you want to pass a reference but the function intends on making a copy.